# call an sql function by name returned by select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, postgresql, t-sql

I would like to find out how to call a function the name of which is returned from a select query. So let's say, I have a select query:

```
SELECT function_name FROM functions WHERE id=1;
```

Now let's say, the returned functions name is fce1
and now I want to execute:

```
SELECT fce1(parameters);
```

Now my initial idea would be:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SELECT function_name FROM functions WHERE id=1;, "(params)");
```

I am quite certain that the idea is wrong. But I was trying to figure that out some time ago and I remember that at least MS SQL was able to achieve my goal and also POSTGRESQL. Anyway, neither do I remember or am I able to find how to do it. Ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: (1) You need to use dynamic SQL for this (or a giant `case` statement.  (2) Are you using SQL Server or Postgres?  Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: I am just in the process of deciding which to use. I would prefer postgres but the decision is based upon the required capability. CASE is not an option really (we are talking about thousands of possible functions).

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @func NVARCHAR(50);

SELECT @func = function_name FROM functions WHERE id=1;

EXEC ('select ' + @func + '()')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all functions return the same data type, you could build a wrapper function in Postgres that you pass the ID of the function to be called:

```
create or replace function call_func(p_id integer)
  returns integer
as
$$
declare 
  l_result integer;
  l_name   text;
  l_params text;
begin 
  select function_name, parameters
    into l_name, l_params
  from functions
  where id = p_id;

  execute 'select '||l_name||'('||l_params||')'
    into l_result;

  return l_result;    
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Note: the above is just an **example**.

It's wide open to SQL injection and does not do any error checking or sanitizing the parameters! But it might point you into the right direction.

Assume you have the functions:

```
create or replace function foo(p_arg_1 integer, p_arg_2 integer)
  returns integer
as
$$
  select p_arg_1 + p_arg_2;
$$
language sql;

create or replace function bar(p_value integer)
  returns integer
as
$$
  select p_value * 4;
$$
language sql;
```

And the `functions` table looks like this:

```
id | function_name | parameters
---+---------------+-----------
 1 | fce           | 42        
 2 | foo           | 1,2
```

You can then do

```
select call_func(2);
```

or

```
select call_func(1);
```

But again: this will only work if all functions return the same result. e.g. scalar functions returning a single value, or set returning functions returning the same table definition.

Comment: I suppose it's only wide open to SQL injection if anyone but the dev/DBA has access to the functions table (or the params it's called with), otherwise it should be ok

Comment: @Charleh: SQL injection is never ok, not even for a developer or DBA. Use quote_ident() to avoid this mistake.

Comment: @FrankHeikens: even if the function name is quoted using `quote_ident()` it would still leave the parameters as a potential "threat" - and I don't see how  they could be escaped/quoted properly to prevent this - but whether or not this is a problem depends on the environment in which this is used. Sometimes this kind of dynamic SQL is not really a problem.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I'd say it's ok if you've considered everything and you are ok with where the data is coming from...plus you can even use it to inject useful code :)